# duplicate tags in nusoap

Tags: php, arrays, soap, nusoap

I'm using [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) to connect to a soap webservice. The xml that the class sends to the service is constructed from an array, ie:

```
$params = array("param1" => "value1", "param2" => "value1");
$client->call('HelloWorld', $params, 'namespace', 'SOAPAction');
```

This works fine. A multidimensional array also constructs a nice nested xml message.

I encounter a problem when i need two tags with the same name:

```
<items>
   <item>value 1</item>
   <item>value 2</item>
</item>

$params = array("items" => array("item" => "value 1", "item" => "value 2"));
```

The second item in the array overwrites the first which results in:

```
<items>
   <item>value 2</item>
</item>
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the inner array()

```
$test_array = array("item" => "value 1", "item" => "value 2");
```

creates an array with a single key ("item").

Try this and see if it works:

```
$params = array("items" => array("item" => array("value 1", "value 2")));
```

No guarantees, though... I haven't used nusoap in a **long** time and don't have PHP installed here to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Your core problem is you're writing invalid PHP code

```
$x = array("items" => array("item" => "value 1", "item" => "value 2")); 
var_dump($x);

array(1) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(7) "value 2"
  }
}
```

Which of course wont work, as its synonymous with

```
 $x = array(); 
 $x['items'] = array(); 
 $x['items']['item']='value 1'; 
 $x['items']['item']='value 2';
```

which of course won't work.

Your best bets are with

```
 array("items"=>array( "value1","value2") );
```

and hoping the numeric keys will "work" 
  or

```
 array("items"=>array("item"=>array("value1","value2")))
```

in the event it is so inclined.

#### Additionally

Looking through the examples on sourceforge, it would appear this is valid syntax:

```
$params = '<person xsi:type="tns:Person"><firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">Willi</firstname><age xsi:type="xsd:int">22</age><gender xsi:type="xsd:string">male</gender></person>';
$result = $client->call('hello', $params);
```

http://nusoap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/nusoap/samples/wsdlclient3b.php

This one shows using an un-keyed ( ie: numeric ) array as an input source: 
http://nusoap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/nusoap/samples/wsdlclient4.php

Answer (score 1):

This is strange because, method:

```
$params = array('items' => array('item' => array('value1', 'value2')))
$client->call( 'action', $params );
```

works form me. As explained 
[in this link](http://osdir.com/ml/php.nusoap.general/2008-02/msg00015.html)

Maybe you need newer version of nusoap?

Answer (score 1):

we have solved this problem by passing string instead of array to nusoap call function.
please check link below
http://fundaa.com/php/solved-duplicate-tags-in-nusoap/

Comment: Please don't just post a link to your own website, post the actual solution here. Or if the solution is very long, at least post a summary in your answer.